# Counting DISTINCT in FULL OUTER JOIN

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I'm sure there's a simple solution to this, which my pea brain is unable to comprehend right now.

I'm using the following query with a `FULL OUTER JOIN` and I would like to COUNT the DISTINCT `memberid`:

```
SELECT a.year,
       COUNT(DISTINCT a.memberid) AS members
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT YEAR,
             memberid
      FROM (SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM created_at) AS YEAR,
                   EXTRACT(MONTH FROM created_at) AS MONTH,
                   member_id AS memberid,
                   COUNT(DISTINCT field1) AS field1
            FROM table1            
            GROUP BY YEAR,
                     MONTH,
                     member_id
            ORDER BY YEAR,
                     MONTH,
                     eids DESC)) a
  FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT YEAR,
                          memberid
                   FROM (SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM created) AS YEAR,
                                EXTRACT(MONTH FROM created) AS MONTH,
                                memberid,
                                COUNT(field2) AS field2
                         FROM table2                        
                         GROUP BY YEAR,
                                  MONTH,
                                  memberid
                         ORDER BY YEAR,
                                  MONTH,
                                  questions DESC)) b
               ON a.year = b.year
              AND a.memberid = b.memberid
GROUP BY a.year
ORDER BY a.year
```

This query executes properly, but I'm quite sure that the results are not what I expect.

I get the following results:

```
2014    26834
2015    58573
2016    178378
2017    233291
2018    297404
2019    281088
```

Let's call the queries on either side of the `FULL OUTER JOIN` as `Left query` and `Right query` for now. When I aggregate the `Right query` on `year` and count the distinct `memberid`, I get the following results:

```
2013    3915
2014    59025
2015    115514
2016    176528
2017    216675
2018    301007
2019    311141
```

As we can see, the results (`DISTINCT COUNT`) for the `Right query` itself is higher than the complete query having the `FULL OUTER JOIN`. This obviously doesn't make sense.

In my final result, I would like to run a `COUNT DISTINCT` on ALL the `memberid` (i.e. the `memberid` that appear in `Left query`, plus the `memberid` that appear in the `Right query`, without counting any `memberid` twice) and aggregate it by `year`.

I know the solution to this has to be simple. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are only counting a.memberid, which means anything from the right side is ignored.

To make this work you should do a union between the left and right side, and then just count(distinct memberid)

Comment: And that did the trick. I don't know why I didn't think about UNION earlier. Thanks so much.